# Change CSS of form builder/runner to show title and input field inline

Tags: css, orbeon

I want to build a form so that every input field will be right after the title with some alignment. The change should effect Form Builder at design time and Form Runner should run same as a design view. Here a short look I want to open each field in form builder.

[click to enter a lebel] **input field**
[click to enter an optional hint]

and form runner will show:

1. Name : Aminul Haque

[error message/hint]

1. Address : Bangladesh

[error message/hint]

i tried to change the css uri in properties-local.xml file as follows and place the form-runner-orbeon.css and form-runner-base.css under /apps/mycss/ directory. then if i change on those css, no effect is shown by form runner.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a CSS wizard, I wouldn't try doing this. You certainly can change/override the default CSS that comes with Form Builder / Form Runner to have the form fields to the right rather than below the labels, but this isn't just done in 10 lines in CSS.